# Given a list of ids, what's the best way to query which ids do not exist in the collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents which contain unique id field. Now I have a list of ids which may contain some ids that do not exist in the collection. What's the best way to find out those ids from the list?

I know I can use $in operator to get the documents which have ids contained in the list then compare with the given id list, but is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately MongoDB can only use built in functions (otherwise I'd recommend using a `set`) but you could try and find all distinct id's in your list then just manually pull them out.

Something like (untested):

```
var your_unique_ids = ["present", "not_present"];

var present_ids = db.getCollection('your_col').distinct('unique_field', {unique_field: {$in: your_unique_ids}});

for (var i=0; i < your_unique_ids.length; i++) {
    var some_id = your_unique_ids[i];
    if (present_ids.indexOf(some_id) < 0) {
        print(some_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ewan. Using distinct is about 50% faster than using $in operator based on my test. I will wait a while to see if there is a better solution pops up and if not, your answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you have the following documents in your collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b725fd7279ca22edb618bb"), "id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b725fd7279ca22edb618bc"), "id" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b725fd7279ca22edb618bd"), "id" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b725fd7279ca22edb618be"), "id" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b725fd7279ca22edb618bf"), "id" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b725fd7279ca22edb618c0"), "id" : 6 }
```

and the following list of `id`

```
var listId = [ 1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 35 ];
```

We can use the [**`.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to return the array of `ids` that is not in your collection.

```
var result = listId.filter(function(el){
    return db.collection.distinct('id').indexOf(el) == -1; });
```

This yields

```
[ 7, 9, 8, 35 ]
```

---

Now you can also use the [*aggregation frameworks*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) and the [`$setDifference`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$group": { "_id": null, "ids": { "$addToSet": "$id" }}}, 
   { "$project" : { "missingIds": { "$setDifference": [ listId, "$ids" ]}, "_id": 0 }}
])
```

This yields:

```
{ "missingIds" : [ 7, 9, 8, 35 ] }
```

Answer (score 4):

Below query will fetch you the result :

```
var listid = [1,2,3,4];

db.collection.aggregate([
 {$project: { uniqueId : 
   {
    "$setDifference": 
        [ listid , db.collection.distinct( "unique_field" )]} , _id : 0 }
   }, 
 {$limit:1}
]);
```