# Mongodb query for search one alphanumeric zipcode between fields

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the zone table in MySQL database, if I execute the following query it works great and returns the record:

```
SELECT *
FROM   zones 
WHERE  zone_structure_id = 2
       AND country_code='CA' 
       AND 'B2H5E1' between from_postal_code and to_postal_code
```

Similar, I have the zone collection in MongoDB.

I want the query to get back the record in MongoDB.

`fromPostalCode : "B2H0A1"` and `toPostalCode : "B2H6B8"`, so if `"B2H5E1"` is with in the range it should return the row.

```
{
 "_id" : { "$oid" : "559b55b9e4b0c262a075e95d"} , 
 "_class" : "com.jiit.restlet.model.Zone" ,
 "zoneId" : 481 ,
 "zoneStructureId" : 2 ,
 "zoneName" : "MAR" ,
 "cityName" : "null" ,
 "provinceCode" : "null" ,
 "countryCode" : "CA" ,
 "fromPostalCode" : "B2H0A1" ,
 "toPostalCode" : "B2H6B8"
}
```

Comment: you need to start [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/crud/)

Comment: `from_postal_code` and `to_postal_code`. Are they column names?

Comment: Yes , they are column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
db.zone.find({ 
    "zoneStructureId" : 2, 
    "countryCode": "CA", 
    "fromPostalCode": { "$lt": "B2H5E1" }, 
    "toPostalCode": { "$gt": "B2H5E1" }
})
```

Comment: @CharlesSelvaraj please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31669322/edit) you question with sample document

Comment: i can't add any images with my question. It shows i need 10 reputation to upload the images.

Comment: [don't add image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) copy/paste

Comment: Sorry, its not working. when i copy/paste the image only the path of the image is displayed.

Comment: **Not the image the document.** [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31663708/3100115) example of document

Comment: Sorry, the column names in MongoDB is different from Mysql. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Awesome its working, but slightly i modified your answer, in "countryCode": "CA'", there is a single quotes added. I removed it and now its working. Thanks a lot.